# Как создать функцию которая будет брать любой тип данных?

Tags: c++

Например, чтобы функция могла печатать любые данные, которые передали в функцию.

```
function("a");
function(5);
function(0.4f);
```

Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template <typename T>
void function(T message) {
 
     cout << "Message: " << message << endl;

}
```